# Powerpoint: Quick Styles only apply partially

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

With Quick Styles in Powerpoint it's possible to choose from a list of styles to apply to a text box. These styles set things like background color, border color and text color.

However, for some boxes, applying a Quick Style doesn't change the text color or border color! For example, a box with white background and black text, when choosing a Quick Style with dark background and light text only changes the background to dark but keeps the black text making it unreadable. But for other boxes, the text color is updated.

I have looked to a way to "un-set" the text color, hoping to make it follow the Quick Style, but I can not find anything like that.

What can I do to force a text box to follow all properties from the Quick Style?